# Timeout HTTP.Get

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api, ssjs, content-builder

Im trying to hit a GET request prior to sending the email, the API is known to lag. It is helpful when we get a timely response but I want it to timeout and send the email anyway if we don't get a response in 5 seconds. I am currently working with the following code but can't seem to get it to work.

```
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
 try {
 setTimeout(function() {
  var email = "myemail@email.com";
  var url = "https://api.com/api/dostuff";
  var request_url = url + email;
  var headerNames = ["X-API-KEY"];
  var headerValues = ["generickey1"];
  var response = HTTP.Get(request_url, headerNames, headerValues);
  Variable.SetValue("@response", response);
  throw "Response Timeout";
 }, 5000);
} catch (e) {
Write(Stringify(e))
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The window/document setTimeout function's browser based. This is SSJS and there's no window or document object to provide this functionality.

You can use the [Script.Util.HttpRequest(](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.htm)) function to set the timeout for your request. If you inspect the returnStatus of the response for a failure, you can handle the error.

```
<script runat="server">
    //Request to URL that takes 10 seconds to respond
    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest("http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/10000/url/http://www.google.co.uk");

    // timeout the call after five seconds
    req.timeout = 5;
    req.method = "GET";
    req.continueOnError = true;

    try {
        var resp = req.send();
        //If timeout or other error, returnStatus is -2
        Platform.Response.Write((resp.returnStatus == 0) ? "Success" : "Timeout");
    } catch (e){
        Platform.Response.Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(e));
    }
</script>
```