# How to change Marketing Cloud Http Request timeout?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, ssjs, httprequest

Is there a way to change MC Http Request timeout?
I think that the default is 30 seconds, but the process we are POSTing to via a form can take more.

I'm using SSJS for the call:

```
var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payloadString, headerNames, headerValues);
```

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.htm from that documentation it sounds like this is a static setting. I am not aware of a possibility to change this. Anyway a form POST with 30 seconds or more of processing sounds a bit "unusual" to me - I would try to address this as the root cause rather than trying to force longer timeouts.

Comment: I believe using Script.Util for the POST instead of HTTP.Post would allow you to set up a custom timeout period. I agree a POST over 30 seconds can be an oddity though and you might want to explore that first (as @JonasLambert stated) and address the sickness before solving for the symptoms.

Comment: This was a similar question I answered a couple of weeks ago https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318487/timeout-http-get/318499#318499. As @Gortonington says, Script.Util.HttpRequest allows you to define the timeout of your request. See the docos... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.htm

Comment: Thanks @Macca! this actually works well.

Comment: The answer was already posted here:
[stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318487/timeout-http-get/318499#318499)